# adding another where condition on inner join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, distinct, where-clause

i got an issue with selecting data from below query based on mtb.mid .
all i want is to select below query base on highest mtb.mid but i cant figure it out where do i need to put that cause on my where clause or other place ....

here is my fine and working query that give me result that i need to add a filter that i talked above .

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT wTB.Week, wTB.Description, wTB.wid, mTB.mid
FROM           yTB INNER JOIN
                         mTB ON yTB.yid = mTB.yid INNER JOIN
                         wTB ON mTB.mid = wTB.mid INNER JOIN
                         dTB ON wTB.wid = dTB.wid
WHERE        (dTB.dateEn <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
ORDER BY wTB.Week
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: side note: `top (100) percent` is meaningless.

Comment: Did you try ordering it by mtb.mid in descending way? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ZoharPeled not always, it is required if part of a sub query

Comment: @CarlSixsmith no, it's not. a subquery is only ever allowed to return a single value, not a result set. perhaps you mean a derived table, and in that case, it's also redundent (and also the order by), since tables are considered unsorted anyway. same goes for views.

Comment: @ZoharPeled they are only unordered if you don't specify an order. And tsql will throw an error if you don't include the top 100 percent and sort order

Comment: @CarlSixsmith: Where ever sql server throws an error on `order by`, it means that the `order by` is irrelevant. Dodging the error with `top 100 percent` is redundant and depending on the query optimizer may even cause worse performance.

Comment: @ZoharPeled interesting. I came across this error the other day. I will revisit and see where my error lies

Comment: @ZoharPeled just found it. Was in a table function. I suppose I n mixing display logic with filter logic and could sort outside the function but it is required inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP (100) PERCENT wTB.Week, wTB.Description, wTB.wid, mTB.mid
FROM           yTB INNER JOIN
                         mTB ON yTB.yid = mTB.yid INNER JOIN
                         wTB ON mTB.mid = wTB.mid INNER JOIN
                         dTB ON wTB.wid = dTB.wid
WHERE        (dTB.dateEn <= CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AND 
             mTB.mid = (SELECT MAX(mid)
                        FROM mTB)
ORDER BY wTB.Week
```

just put that condition in WHERE clause and use Subquery to get highest mTB.mid value from mTB table.

Comment: thanks m8 , i did that before but somehow i manage to miss type the select cause and that gave me headache ! thanks again